# Save all the key pressed in a textarea and sent it to a PHP server?

Tags: php, javascript

The task is to save all the key pressed in a text area and their timestamp. When a button is pressed the values will be sent to the server for processing. I have the javascript that detects the key. I understand I will probably have to do an ajax request to send the data from the client to the server.

I'm not sure what solutions should I use:

- cookies ?
- html 5 local storage ?

I'm not limited by old browsers like IE6/7.

I'm only interested in a pseudo code for this process.

Comment: wait.. do what? you just mentioned AJAX to server. i thought you were going the right way. then you took right turn.. then cookies? local storage?

Comment: you can't make 1 request for each key pressed, it's not really the optimum solution

Comment: you have text area just grab its contents and send them accross on button click unless certain keys you are storing in an Array? or they are so many which can't fit size of array ? is that why you want to use local storage or cookies ?

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz, I also need the timestamp for each keypressed

Answer (score 0):

Very pseudo code:

```
var buffer = ""
onkey = function
    buffer += lastKey
    if buffer.length >= x or timeSinceLastPost > y
        ajaxRequest(buffer)
        buffer = ""
```

If all you want to do is to buffer a few keystrokes to avoid swamping the server, the above logic will do. You only need to buffer the data in a Javascript variable. No local storage of any other kind necessary.

Alternatively, if you want to send the *entire* text content on each request, but not keep sending requests on every keystroke while the user is typing, this'll help:

```
var timeout
onkey = function
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function ajaxRequest(textContent), 1000)
```

This will delay each request by a second and cancel any existing timeouts while the user keeps typing. In essence, it submits the query when the user has stopped typing for one second.

Answer (score 0):

why not store the keycode and timestamp in an object, push it into an array and have a sender script send it to the server from time to time? like (pseudocode):

```
onkeydown(e):
    var stroke = {}                 //create a stroke
    var stroke.keyCode = e.keyCode  //get what was pressed
    var stroke.time = getTime()     //get when it was pressed
    strokes.push(stroke)            //put in collection
```

and your stroke collection will look like this:

```
var strokes = [
    {keyCode: 43, time: 20120101235959},
    {keyCode: 46,time: 201201012355958} //and so on...
]
```

then set a timer to periodically send the data. clone the current status of the array (incase the user is still typing) and the clone's length. send the data to the server. and if the server replies a success, remove the first `n` strokes from the collection where `n` was the number of strokes that were cloned and sent.

```
setTimeout(5 mins):
    var strokesToSend = copy(strokes)
    var strokesLength = strokesToSend.length

    sendToServer(url,strokesToSend):
        strokes.splice(0,strokes.length)
```

that way, you have a continuous collect-and-send of strokes but not a continuously long collection. if the server fails to receive, then the collection will still continue and the unsent data will be sent the next time.